# Get ID of SVG element after mouse click using POST method and process it with PHP

Tags: php, svg

I would like to get the id of the svg element after a mouse click and process it using a PHP script. **This needs to be done without the use of javascript**. The html page contains inline svg.

In the following example, I would like to get the ID of circle element (#mycircle) when clicked with a mouse using POST method. Then process it with a PHP script with the value from $_POST['mycircle'].

Eg (may not be a valid svg or html code for the sake of brevity):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SVG_id to PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <svg>
                 <symbol id=colony_circle><circle cx=10 cy=10 r=4 /></symbol>
                 <use xlink:href=#colony_circle id="mycircle" x="10" y="10"/>
            </svg>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the svg's ***foreignObject*** element and positioning it exactly on top of the desired svg element (Eg: circle). When you click the circle, the submit button is activated. The svg_action.php processes it and prints the value of the hidden input type.

**svg_view.php file:**

```
<?php
echo "<svg id=svg1 version=1.1";
echo " xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
echo " xmlns:xlink=http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
echo "x='0px' y='0px'";
echo " viewBox='0 0 400 160'";
echo "enable-background='new 0 0 400 160'";
echo " xml:space=preserve>";
?>
<circle cx="60" cy="80" r="30" fill="#00ff00" fill-opacity="0.5" />
<foreignObject x="32" y="53" width="200" height="150">
<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <form method=post action="svg_action.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="circleXYZ" /> 
        <input type="submit" style="background-color: #00ff00; width: 55; height: 55; border-radius: 50%;" value="" />
    </form>
</body>
</foreignObject>

</svg>
```

**svg_action.php file:**

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST['hidden']);
?>
```

Probably, there may be a better way to solve it without javascript!